# SharePoint 2013 people picker

Tags: 2013, people-picker

How to disable  specific people picker field in a list in edit form . Not all the people picker field present  in that  specific list. 
Below code disable all people picker field

$(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").css({ 'display' : 'none'});
$(".sp-peoplepicker-editorInput").css({ 'display' : 'none'});

I want to disable specific people picker field.

Comment: require more information, can you be more specific and provide few screen shots of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a list in which I have 3 people picker column .out of which I want to disable only one people picker column in my edit form based on particular security group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery selectors, you can target a specific column using the internal name. Below is the selector **^** which means "*Begins with*".

```
$("input[id^='internalColumnName']").prop("disabled", true);
$(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage[id^='internalColumnName']").prop("disabled", true);
$(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage[id^='internalColumnName']").css({"display": "none"});
```

Comment: Glad to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a text area that is currently set as a people picker, and you no longer want it to be set as such, you can change the type to a single line of text, etc.  In the List Settings, click the field in question, and change the type from there.

Comment: No I want to disable specific people picker field in edit form

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'contentEditable' property of the people picker field to **false**.

- To disable all the people picker fields - `$('[title="People Picker"]').attr("contentEditable","false");`
- To disable a specific people picker - `$('#divID').attr("contentEditable","false");`, where divID is the ID of the people picker div